# _text postgres data type

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I get a table with type _text

> create table mt ( id int8,
> directions _text null)

Its not my code so I don't know what is type _text and how to work with it.
I look for it in doc https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype.html
but I didn't find.

My question is does anybody works with _text  in postgresql? I need an examples.

Comment: I think, it can be custom, how can I get all custom data types name in postgresql? Maybe there is a table with names and descriptions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the internal type name for an array. Similar to `int8` being the internal name for `bigint`.

So your statement is the same as:

```
create table mt 
(
  id bigint,
  directions text[]
)
```

I can't find the reference any more, but the reason was that `[]` is invalid in an identifier (and a type name *is* an identifier) and thus array types are identified with the `_` prefix in `pg_type`

This is detectable through the pg_type system catalog:

```
select bt.typname as base_type, 
       at.typname as array_type
from pg_type bt
  join pg_type at on bt.typarray = at.oid
where bt.typnamespace = 'pg_catalog'::regnamespace  
order by bt.typname
```

`pg_type.typarray` links to the pg_type row that contains the array type for the base type.

Laurenz answered a similar question on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/307344) with some more technical insight.

Comment: Yes, seems its true, I already saw it in my database

Comment: @yuoggy: note that with the usual Postgres tools, you would never see `_text` in any generated DDL statement. The statement you have seen, must have been reverse engineered by a tool that doesn't understand the Postgres type system.

Comment: A related question is [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/307344/176905).